# What was the smallest monetary claim settled by SCOTUS, inflation adjusted?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court

This is similar to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83969/what-has-been-the-teeniest-claim-for-damages-at-the-high-court-of-australia), but for the US Supreme Court. What is the smallest monetary claim, adjusted for inflation, settled by the SCOTUS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Uzuegbunam v. Preczewski* (2021), the US Supreme Court addressed a case that sought one dollar in nominal damages.

<sub>I'm assuming you mean only claims involving money damages as a remedy, because there are many claims every year involving no literal money damages and the remedy sought is some other kind of relief (although such relief would still have practical or economic value).</sub>

Comment: In the UK, Martina Navratilova was ordered to pay £1 in damages for destroying a paparazzi's camera, some long time ago. With inflation she would be ordered to pay £2 if it happened today (I wonder if there's a limit, that a court cannot order less than £1 in damages? )